# NavigationBar Item doesn't appear anymore after screen rotation SwiftUI iOS 14

Tags: swift, swiftui, navigationbar, navigationview, navigationbaritems

I have a simple pattern : a list view with a detail view. Both have navigation bar item.

Problem:
Only on the detail view when I rotate the screen to landscape, the navigation bar item disappears and will never appear anymore even If I rotate back. This bug occurs only on iOS14.

ListView :

```
NavigationView{
    ZStack{
    (List and NavigationLink...)
    }.navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(...))
    .sheet(someSheet...)
}.navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle())
```

DetailView :

```
ZStack {
    (someView...)
    .navigationBarTitle(...)
    .navigationBarItems(trailing: Button(...))
    .sheet(someSheet...)
}
```

Comment: just to confirm, this bug has happened to me too. I'm curious to know if you're having this issue only on iPad or not.

Comment: It's an iPhone app. I don't test it on iPad.

Comment: @MahdiBM did you fix it ?

Comment: not exactly a `Fix`, but rather a workaround. navigation items dont appear because they are too far to the left/right, so you can just use a spacer(minLength: (heightOfScreen - widthOfScreen) / 2)  to make them come to the visible area.  i've also only experienced this but on iPad, not iPhone

Comment: I don't succeeded to move it again to visible area on iPhone.